# What is the difference between using Sink and Pipe with Streams in Dart?

Tags: dart, stream, pipe, sink

```
import "dart:async";
import "dart:html";

void main() async {
  InputElement addStream = querySelector("#addstream");

  Stream<int> aStream = _someStream();
  StreamController<int> sc = StreamController();

  sc.stream.listen((e) => print(e));

  addStream.onClick.listen((e) {
  sc.sink.addStream(aStream);  // streamcontroller brings in stream through the sink
  // aStream.pipe(sc);   // stream going into streamcontroller through the sink
  });
}
```

In the code above, `sc.sink.addStream(aStream)` seems to use the sink method to add `aStream` to `StreamController` sc.
Under that, `aStream` uses `pipe` to get added to `StreamController sc`.

Both methods seem to do the same thing.  It seems to me that using one method over the other is simply style.  If you are using a `Stream`, `pipe` it to the `StreamController`.  If you are using a `StreamController`, sink a `Stream` to it.  Is there a particular reason to use one versus the other?

Comment: Note that `sc.sink` is the same as `sc`. So `sc.sink.addStream(aStream)` is the same as `sc.addStream(aStream);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`aStream.pipe(sc)` will `close()` the stream controller after the stream is finished. With `sc.addStream(aStream)` the controller will still be open after the stream is done, so you can add more events or other streams.

The call to `Stream.pipe` in this case would be identical to `sc.addStream(aStream).then((_) sc.close());`